# RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds in WASM

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm, wasm-pack

I am currently building a small project that outsources it's processing into wasm compiled from rust. I am using wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack and webpack. Shortly after the WASM is instantiated, I get the error described above. When looking at the wat format, it tries to access memory `f32.store offset=9331392` at ~9mb into the buffer. When I inserted `console.log(wasm.memory.buffer.byteLength)` into the glue code, it says that only 4mb is available. Does anyone know how I can either:

- make the memory grow dynamically
- set an initial memory size

Help would very much be appreciated. This is my first time using rust/wasm and I don't know how to increase the memory size here.

Edit:

### Source code

*lib.rs*

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::{prelude::*, Clamped, JsCast};
use web_sys::ImageData;

extern crate wee_alloc;

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;

#[allow(dead_code)]
fn main() {
    #[wasm_bindgen]
    pub struct Simulation {
        ...
    }

    #[wasm_bindgen]
    impl Simulation {
        #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Result<Simulation, JsValue> {
            ...
        }

        fn render(...) -> Result<(), JsValue> {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which allocator are you using? I think wee_alloc is considered deprecated despite being recommend in the docs

Comment: As I said, this is my first time using rust with wasm, so I am basically just copying examples and modifying them to my needs. I have added wee_alloc to my code, but the same thing is still happening. I am gonna add some code to my question, maybe this helps.

Comment: got it once and then it disappeared without any traces :/